# SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I just started learning javascript and I am trying to create a recursive function to find the smallest value in an array , but this error occured. I am not very familiar with javascript syntax and I cannot make out what is wrong with my code.

```
function min(array) {
counter = 0;
function check(y) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; len = array.length ; i < len ; i++ ) { 
        if ( y > array[i] ) {
            check(array[counter++]);
        }
    }

    return array[counter] ;     
}

check(array[counter]);


}
```

**Also here is a screenshot of the error :**

[image]

Comment: Check variables declaration in for loop...

Comment: for () has three parts (init, condition, increment). You have 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for ( var i = 0 ; len = array.length ; i < len ; i++ );
```

to

```
for ( var i = 0, len = array.length ; i < len ; i++ ){
               ^                                     ^
```

Comment: Wait...I missed that comma, you are right. Thank you very much. :)